# Managing dependencies between modules that rely on each other

Tags: architecture, software-design, circular-dependency

I have a problem figuring out how to structure my application. I have several modules that manage users, groups, roles, memberships, and oauth clients respectively. Now I want to add authentication/authorization on top of/in these modules, but the auth is kind of dependent on the previously mentioned modules. To me this sounds like it would cause some circular dependencies, which I'd like to stay away from. Is there some clever way to structure code/modules to avoid that?

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle for dependency management?

Answer (score 0):

Create a third module which abstracts away the minimum necessary service authentication functionality, and have the original two modules depend on that (instead of each other). This may seem like a lot of work at first, but the dependency management simplification pays off quickly.